# Do delegated events in jQuery remain intact when the event context is set to `display:none`?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

So if I do:

```
$('#foobar-parent').delegate('#foobar', 'click', function(){
    //do something after #foobar-child is clicked
});
```

Will the event still work if I set `#foobar-parent` to `display:none;` then back to `display:block;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a style of `display: none` doesn't change the DOM in any way or change the functioning any of the event listeners.  It only changes the visibility upon rendering.

But, if `foobar-parent` is set to `display: none`, then all of it's children are also going to be hidden so it's going to be hard for any of them to get a click event while it's `display: none` since they are all hidden too.

But, as soon as it is set back to `display: block` and it's children are again visible and click events can again happen, the `delegate()` event processing will work just fine.  Event listeners are not affected by the value of the display style setting.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/chF8S/.